# Firebase Pod Code Changing

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I am currently following a tutorial for a google sign in page: https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_1559434257&feature=iv&src_vid=tYtBX6efJkc&v=rDKtMz_PcLQ&spfreload=5

While going through the tutorial, at 7:49, the code shown is:

FIRApp.config()

.....FIRApp

and for some reason this isn't showing even though I have the pods for Firebase and Google. FIRApp is shown as an error because of this.

EDIT --

I ended up getting it to work by just doing these imports:

pod Firebase/Auth
pod GoogleSignIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if i understood what you mean, you are saying that you done `import Firebase` and `FIRApp` just doesn't work like you didn't import anything.

Try to `build` your app every time that you add a new pod, because some times xcode just recognize your pods after a build.

Note: I think that you know that, but the right is:

```
FIRApp.configure()
```

Comment: I already build my app every time I add a new pod. I am still having problems in writing the code. I think that FIRApp is now called FirebaseApp, but configure is not available when I try to do FirebaseApp.configure()

Comment: Take a look at the firebase documentation:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup. You will see that it's FIRApp. This tutorial that you are following is from this month, so it is probably updated. Have you configured your app with your firebase app?

Comment: How exactly am I supposed to configure my app with the firebase app

Comment: When you create a new project on firebase, it asks you to configure it passing your app bundle identifier and add a info.plist to your app's project. Also, make sure that you are using the right pod. Try to follow the documentation, would be really good btw.